# Difference between electron, muon and tau neutrinos

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, antimatter

What is the difference between the neutrinos of electron, muon and tau leptons.? They all same to be neutral and carry a very small mass. Similarly what is the difference bewteen anti neutrinos of electron, muon and tau leptons

Comment: What is the difference between electrons, muons, and taus? As Rabi famously asked of the muon, “Who ordered *that*?”.

Answer (score 2):

The three leptons each carry their own "flavor"; tau type, muon type and electron type.  This flavor is conserved in lepton decays.  For example when a negative muon decays to an electron, the decay produces $\mu^- \rightarrow e^- + \bar{\nu_e} + \nu_\mu $.  Note that two neutrinos are required in this decay.  A $\nu_\mu$ conserves muon flavor on both sides of the equation and a $\bar{\nu_e} + e^-$ leaves a net zero (-1 + 1 = 0) electron flavor on both sides of the equation.  What "exactly" is different about these neutrinos is hard to say  though.